How to check if row (record) exists that was created during current month in EF Core
I would like to know if there is any more efficient way to check if I have a record that was created during the current month (June 2024)?
Currently I use multiple conditions, but don't know if there is a more efficient way with DateTime?


var hasTransferFromCurrentMonth = await _dbContext.Transfers
  .Where(p => p.ReceiverId == transferDto.ReceiverId &&
    p.CreatedDate.Month == DateTime.UtcNow.Month &&
    p.CreatedDate.Year == DateTime.UtcNow.Year)
  .AnyAsync();




As a general rule for peak efficiency LINQ to EF queries, you should avoid calculations or function calls within the query if possible and execute this logic first. So for date ranges, we can calculate the boundary dates first and then use simple between logic:
DateTime currentMonthStart = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(-DateTime.UtcNow.Day + 1);
DateTime nextMonthStart = currentMonthStart.AddMonths(1);

var hasTransferFromCurrentMonth = await _dbContext.Transfers
     .Where(p => p.ReceiverId == transferDto.ReceiverId 
              && p.CreatedDate >= currentMonthStart 
              && p.CreatedDate < nextMonthStart)
     .AnyAsync();

This is more efficient because no transformation needs to be made against the data we are querying, instead the RDBMS only needs to compare against the raw data values.

NOTE: I have used less than the next month to cover all time values for the last day. A common mistake in this area if your data has a non-zero time component and you use less than or equal to the last day of the month then it will exclude any records that occur on the last day of the month.

There is added benefits here that if you have an index on the CreatedDate column then the RDBMS should be able to use an Index Seek instead of more expensive scan operations.

There are exceptions to these rules, this is general advice, and to optimise LINQ to EF it is usually a good idea to inspect the SQL that is generated and then look to see if you can improve your query to generate more efficient SQL.
Different RDBMS also optimise Date queries and Date functions used in filter criteria in different ways, however this will produce the best results without changing your DB schema.
